# Scroll an ASP page to an error message

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net-2010

I have an ASP page which contains a table with rows containing different controls.

One of them contains Date of Birth (Combo for Month and Day, Text box for Year). I am going to  validate this date entered by the user. If any error occurs I display this error message as label text. I am able to validate this and pop-up an error into the label.

My problem is that I want the control to go that place (DOB row) and the page has to scroll upwards. Currently the message is being displayed and the page is visible from start and user has to manually scroll down to see that error.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out HTML anchors (first result on Google: http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html) and just redirect to that tag to jump the error message ala:

```
<div name = "ErrorDiv">Error</div>
```

And then in your code behind

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}#{1}", Request.RawUrl, "ErrorDiv"));
```

Obviously you can do the same thing client side as well, but it sounded like you were doing your validation exclusively on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin named "ScrollSaver".
All you have to do is to include that .js file in your asp page.
It saves the location of each element in a cookie and then restores it when the page is getting re-rendered.

For more information: read, http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver